# How to get the top N percent (e.g., 50%) of a table in BigQuery (standard SQL)?

Tags: sql, count, google-bigquery, sql-order-by, window-functions

I have tried the following approaches which none of them worked:

1. Using `SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT`: BigQuery does not have top function
2. Using `LIMIT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabl)/2`: the reason is BigQuery does not accept any non integer value.
3. Using `SET` to set the median value and then use `WHERE`

Comment: "**Top** N percent" or just "N percent"?

Comment: "Top N percent" or "Bottom N percent"

Answer (score 6):

In BigQuery I would use [window function `percent_rank()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#percent_rank).

```
select t.* except (prnk)
from (select t.*, percent_rank() over(order by id) prnk from mytable t) t
where prnk <= 0.5
```

Note: any answer to your question will require that you provide a column to order your data. I assumed that this column is called `id`.

Answer (score 1):

One method uses window functions:

```
select t.* except (seqnum, cnt)
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by ?) as seqnum,
             count(*) over () as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= cnt / 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility would be to limit the data with a WHERE clause instead of LIMIT. This is an example if you want yo filter by an ID:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name as t
WHERE t.id <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name)/2;
```

And if you want to filter by the row number:

```
SELECT t.* except (rn)
FROM (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS rn
    FROM table_name as t
) AS t
WHERE t.rn <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name)/2;
```

Answer (score 1):

To scale up, you can use an approx algorithm to find the 50% point:

```sql
DECLARE mid_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT (
  SELECT APPROX_QUANTILES(creation_date, 2)[OFFSET(1)] mid_date
  FROM `fh-bigquery.stackoverflow_archive.201909_posts_answers` )
;

SELECT mid_date
  , COUNTIF(creation_date > mid_date) first_half
  , COUNTIF(creation_date < mid_date) second_half
FROM `fh-bigquery.stackoverflow_archive.201909_posts_answers`
```

Looks like it works well:

[image]

Now let's get these records out:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `temp.fifty_percent`
AS
SELECT *
FROM `fh-bigquery.stackoverflow_archive.201909_posts_answers` 
WHERE creation_date < (
  SELECT APPROX_QUANTILES(creation_date, 2)[OFFSET(1)] mid_date
  FROM `fh-bigquery.stackoverflow_archive.201909_posts_answers` 
)
```

This method will happily scale, while solutions using `OVER(ORDER BY)` won't.